# How do I stack bootstrap grid columns one below the other instead of one beside another?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just beginning to learn Bootstrap and I came across the grid system. I was playing around and noticed that the grid columns always start from the left and go towards the right, placing the divs one beside another. How do I make them appear one below the other?
Here's some sample code:

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Three Equal Columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 bg-success">.col-1</div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-warning">.col-2</div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-success">.col-3</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Here's a fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/txdqjf8b/2/

How do I make `col-1`, `col-2` and `col-3` appear one below the other, so that later if I have a `col-4`, `col-5` and `col-6`, I want them like this:

```
col-1    col-4    col-7
col-2    col-5    col-8 
col-3    col-6    col-9
```

Comment: I think instead of modifying how bootstrap is intended to render columns, you should restructure how you want the output.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean why are you calling it `col-1` `col-2` etc when it should be `row-1` `row-2` etc?  In bootstrap, `.row` is used to make a div appear one below another, not the `.col-` class

Comment: I guess you have to generate the data accordingly and print the data like `1 - 4 - 6` and so on. \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bootstrap 4, there is a option of ordering your elements using `order-lg/md/sm/xs-1` like below.

```
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-1 bg-success">.col-1</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-4 bg-warning">.col-2</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-7 bg-success">.col-3</div>
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 bg-success">.col-4</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-5 bg-warning">.col-5</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-8 bg-success">.col-6</div>
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-3 bg-success">.col-7</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-6 bg-warning">.col-8</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-9 bg-success">.col-9</div>
```

I have updated your fiddle. Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/txdqjf8b/4/)

You can get more clarity in docs https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order

The above code I have done it for applying only medium size screens. Like that way you can decide your order for large and small screen. Suppose if you want to apply commonly then use `order-1` like below.

```
<div class="col-4 order-1 bg-success">.col-1</div> 
<div class="col-4 order-4 bg-warning">.col-2</div> 
<div class="col-4 order-7 bg-success">.col-3</div>
<div class="col-4 order-2 bg-success">.col-4</div> 
<div class="col-4 order-5 bg-warning">.col-5</div> 
<div class="col-4 order-8 bg-success">.col-6</div>
<div class="col-4 order-3 bg-success">.col-7</div> 
<div class="col-4 order-6 bg-warning">.col-8</div> 
<div class="col-4 order-9 bg-success">.col-9</div>
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/txdqjf8b/5/)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 bg-success">.col-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">.col-2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 bg-success">.col-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused why the answer is downvoted.  Please let me know the reason for the downvote. It will help me improve.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-3</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-6</div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 bg-success">col-9</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in CSS3 when you can define an element with multiple columns. But, I don't think that all the browser supports this feature.

Or it may conflict with the bootstrap css.

```
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
column-count: 3;
```

```css
.row {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
.col{
 width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">col 1</div>
    <div class="col">col 2</div>
    <div class="col">col 3</div>
    <div class="col">col 4</div>
    <div class="col">col 5</div>
    <div class="col">col 6</div>
</div>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

Answer (score -1):

For googlers:
If you want to do this without Bootstrap, or if you are using Bootstrap 3, you can simply use a display: grid, using grid-auto-flow: column.

I created an example, you can check here:

```css
.grid-rows {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

codepen.io/mauricio-paz/pen/RwNPqyM